# Coding a regex to return true for an EXACT count of a group

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I'm using the regex below to return numbers that contain exactly 3 instances of the digits 6,7 and 8 (with 0 to many other digits between each).  I know there has to be a way to match exactly 3 without matching more instances but I can't find it anywhere.

```
echo $num | egrep '(6.*|7.*|8.*){3}' | egrep -v '(6.*|7.*|8.*){4}' | egrep -v '(6.*|7.*|8.*){5}'`
```

I'm trying to match numbers like 4561863 but not 466773.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to first match any number of digits that *aren't* 6, 7, or 8, then match 3 groups of numbers that start with a 6, 7, or 8 followed by any number of not-6,7,8.

```
echo "$num" | grep -E '^[0-5,9]*([6-8][0-5,9]*){3}$'
```

Comment: I forgot the `-E` option; without that, you need to escape the parentheses and the braces, like so: `[0-5,9]*\([6-8][0-5,9]*\)\{3\}`.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks, that does exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an example Regex](https://regex101.com/r/vMRlmP/2) that appears to work.

```
echo "$num" | grep -E '\b[^678]*[678][^678]*[678][^678]*[678][^678]*\b'
```

You want to match zero or more non-678, one 678, zero or more non-678, one 678, zero or more non-678, one 678, and finally zero or more non-678 within each number.

Comment: `[^678]` assumes that `$num` contains only digits.

Comment: Of course `$num` contains only digits. The OP said `I'm trying to match numbers like 4561863 but not 466773.`